# Which is correct: "home in" or "hone in"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, differences, idioms, confusables

I've heard people say "**Home** in on something", but I've also heard others say "**Hone** in on something".

Which is the correct expression, and what is the etymology of these?

Comment: Interesting, I was playing a game of Carcassonne with friends and an argument ensued when I said I was going to **horn in** on a city. They insisted that I meant *hone in*. I said no, I definitely mean to "participate without invitation."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**[Home in](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Home+in)** is correct.  It bears resemblance to the concept of "home" in that the projectile (or a figurative counterpart) involved is getting to where it is meant to go.  However, the variation "hone in" has increasingly been accepted to mean the same thing.

Also see definition #21 here of *[home](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Home)*, and [this very helpful study](http://grammar.about.com/od/alightersideofwriting/a/homehonegloss.htm) on the two commonly confused expressions.

This reports the following:

> Traditionally, a missile homes in (not hones in) on a target. Hone means "to sharpen." The verb home means "to move toward a goal" or "to be guided to a target." But some usage guides (see notes below) now recognize hone in on as an acceptable alternative to home in on.

An [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=homed%20in%20on,honed%20in%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) illustrates the wider usage of "home in on" than "hone in on", at least in current literature.

Comment: As in a *homing pigeon* -- I thought so, and it's my preferred version of the phrase.

Comment: And if I ever hear anyone say "honing pigeon", I'll ask them what material is sharpened by the pigeon.

Comment: @pavium very sharp comment there!

Answer (score 5):

@zenbike ... I was a Soldier and I never heard "hone in on target" while I was on active duty.

From the OED on my computer and online:

> verb [ no obj. ]
>   1. (of an animal) return by instinct to its territory after leaving it: a dozen geese homing to their summer nesting grounds.
>   • (of a pigeon bred for long-distance racing) fly back to or arrive at its loft after being released at a distant point.
>   2. (home in on) move or be aimed toward (a target or destination) with great accuracy: more than 100 missiles were launched, **homing in on** radar emissions.
>   • focus attention on: a teaching style that **homes in on** what is of central importance for each student.

From etymology online:

> home (v.) 1765, "to go home", from home (n.). Meaning "**be guided to a destination by radio signals, etc**. (of missiles, aircraft, etc.) is from 1920; it had been used earlier in reference to pigeons (1862). Related: Homed; homing. O.E. had hamian "to establish in a home".

You can hone your skills but you ***home in*** on a target.

Comment: Homing requires a signal drawing you to a destination. As in a laser designator on the target, or a source of radio emissions. If there is no such source, how do you home in on the target?

Comment: No, homing does not require a signal. The meaning began with homing pigeons ... they certainly did not (and still do not) have a radio signal to home in on (year 1862, see the etymology online info above). ... When you find your way home (home in) do you need a signal? I hope not.

Answer (score 2):

There's an article in *[World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-hom1.htm)* on just this subject.  To summarize, apparently "home in" is the original correct usage, but "hone in on" is in wider use.  Technically "home in" is the correct usage and "hone in" is not, but the majority of the public will likely think "home in" to be a mistake and that it should be "hone in."

Comment: So the argument that usage is more important than strict definition, comes to the fore, and I'll have to get used to it.

Comment: On matters like this, it comes down to if one wishes to be right or if one would rather people to think them to be right.  Of course, the latter runs the risk of dealing with people who know better.

Comment: "hone in" in wider use? Not looking forward to "nuculur" getting standardized...

Comment: Looking at NGram American English only (Brits hardly ever make this mistake), it seems 25% of 50,000 usages are for *hone in*. I'm appalled, but even in the US that's considerably less than "the majority of the public".

Comment: As both are arguably colloquialisms whose property of correctness is based in the usage of the phrase, why is either more correct? I promise you that no projectile has a "home" before it is fired, and that a while a homing pigeon does, before that property of some pigeons to always return to a nesting place was known, it would have been quite unusual to call it such. My experience of the phrase to "hone in on" is its common usage in military company. It means to bring an edge closer to perfection. Used in the context of mission or job performance, it means to sharpen your ability to perform.

Comment: Perhaps those of you who have heard it used incorrectly, are hearing persons who have heard it used in that context, and are confusing the two separate expressions?

Comment: @zenbike: To *hone* means to *sharpen*. It doesn't make any sense to speak of *honing in on* something - that's why it's "incorrect", and World Wide Words is simply mistaken in claiming it's the more common version.

Comment: Curious. There are 4 upvotes for my comment pointing out that usage figures from NGram massively discredit the World Wide Words article, which is effectively all this answer consists of. But currently the only downvote for the (IMHO incorrect) answer itself is my own.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I didn't respond or draw my comment from World Wide Words, but it is correct, and at least in the military community, it is the more common usage.

Comment: @zenbike: Well, I know nothing of American military usage, which seems to be a law unto itself *(Hooah!)*. But *home* is twice as common overall in Google Books US, and five times more common in GB UK, so it remains the case that this answer is *incorrect* in saying *"hone in on" is in wider use*. That may be true of the US military, but it's certainly not true of the wider community of Anglophones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it's possible that there is a bit less distinction between the 'm' sound and the 'n' sound in most American accents than there is in most British accents. A lot of American speech seems to de-emphasise some consonants to me, in fact some seem to be almost skipped over. This might explain the greater prevalence of 'hone in' in the US. I also wonder whether zenbike's experience is a result of hearing what he expected to hear rather than hearing what was actually said.

Comment: @BoldBen: I can easily see that the difference between /n/ and /m/ might be harder to detect / articulate in certain sequences. The word ***input*** comes to mind as "easily misheard", and I've certainly seen ***inpatient*** instead of ***impatient*** more than once. But when they come before a ***vowel***, as in ***home / hone in***, I'd have thought it would be far more obvious whether the lips were closed (**/m/**) or not (**/n/**).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was thinking of the duration of the sound more than its actual formation, the briefer the pronunciation the more difficult it is to hear the difference. Also once you've adopted one pronunciation you will expect to hear it in context whatever was actually said. I think, perhaps, than zenbike has been brought up in a family where "hone in" was the accepted version, even to the point where the "sharpen your attention" explanation was passed from parent to child.

Comment: @BoldBen: Like the poor, Spoonerisms, Mondegreens, Eggcorns, and Malapropisms will always be with us. And every now and then *(an **orange**, an **apron**, a whole **nother** ballgame)* the lunatics get to take over the asylum and introduce the odd *permanent* change. (But I doubt ***hone in*** will be one of those! :)

Answer (score 1):

*Hone* means to sharpen a tool/instrument or figuratively implies improving the efficiency of something whereas *home in* on someone means to target someone directly. E.g., "The finance minister is homing in on Uber and its ilk after induction of 10% surcharge on the 'super-rich' in the budget." On the flip side, tax benefits could hone investments.